# como hago para traer todos los datos de una tabla intermedia usando sequelize?

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js

Tengo una asociación M:N (de muchos a muchos) en la base de datos pero cuando se ejecuta la funcion findAll de las M filas incluyendo las N-a filas asociadas a cada una de las M filas los únicos valores que incluye sequelize de la tabla intermedia son las foreign keys y los valores created_at y updated_at, no sé como hacer para que traiga los demás valores que hay en la tabla intermedia sin incluir ésta en los argumentos del findAll (este último paso genera conflictos que tampoco pude resolver), gracias por la lectura, Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Cuando hablamos de la [*cardinalidad*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_entidad-relación#Correspondencia_de_cardinalidades) N:M, N y M representan el número de entidades con las que se relacionan. Por lo tanto, cada vez que escribes *"M tablas"* se pierde totalmente el sentido, considerando también que en la expresión de cardinalidad sólo participan dos tablas, no muchas.

Comment: @Sal se agradece su comentario, procedo a editar la publicación en éste momento.